# How do I install WinConn under Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: package-management

I cannot install WinConn under Ubuntu 13.04

```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:realender/winconn
[sudo] password for gvallver: 
Vous allez ajouter le PPA suivant à votre système :
 WinConn RemoteApp connection manager
 Plus d’info : https://launchpad.net/~realender/+archive/winconn
Appuyez sur [ENTRÉE] pour continuer ou Ctrl-C pour annuler l’ajout

gpg: le porte-clefs « /tmp/tmpg8dqng/secring.gpg » a été créé
gpg: le porte-clefs « /tmp/tmpg8dqng/pubring.gpg » a été créé
gpg: demande de la clef 9CEE05AF sur le serveur hkp keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpg8dqng/trustdb.gpg : base de confiance créée
gpg: clef 9CEE05AF : clef publique « Launchpad PPA for Alex Stanev » importée
gpg: Quantité totale traitée : 1
gpg:               importées : 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

# gvallver@kiwi  ~
> sudo apt-get update
Atteint http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Atteint http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg         
...
...
291 ko réceptionnés en 4s (62,2 ko/s)
W: Impossible de récupérer http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Impossible de récupérer http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

On the website of WinConn it is said that WinConn is built for 12.04 and 12.10. But is there a way to install it on 13.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the .deb files directly from the Launchpad site (press *View package details* > click on the package and the the .deb file on the list of files) and install it with

`sudo dpkg -i foo_downloaded_package`

It should work and install the package, ignore any **Package is of low quality** warnings and if you find any further errors post them in to your question.

You can also edit your apt sources file and replace *raring* with *quantal* so that the package is updated from that PPA with the new versions released for Quantal.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, changin the distro name to quantal main, like this:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo nano realender-ubuntu-winconn-yakkety.list

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu quantal main
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>; <kbd>y</kbd>

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install winconn
```

Done!